# Service Fabric hosted Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-service-fabric

I've created a simple Stateful Actor and a Web API (self hosted) and deployed it to Azure. It has worked and I can browse the nodes in the Service Fabric Explorer.

Azure gives me a url but when I add /api/values to the end (which works fine locally) it downloads a file called values and I can't open it as it is a binary file.

I want to call the web api from a Xamarin app (ie normal Rest api call) but if I can't call it via a browser I'm a bit stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have discovered what was missing.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-creation-via-portal/

This link here walks through creating the Service Fabric app on Azure and in particular the field "Application input endpoints" needs to have the port you want to use. For the samples, they are mostly port 80 or 8081.

There is supposed to be a way to add these ports afterwards which I tried (and so did a Microsoft support engineer) and it did not seem to work. You are supposed to be able to add these ports to the Load Balancer associated with the Service Fabric App.

I recreated my Service Fabric app, exactly as I did before but this time filled in the ports I want to use in the Node Type section and now I can hit the webapi services I've deployed. This field can be left blank which is what I did first time round and was why I had issues.

Answer (score 4):

I would comment this on [Stephen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35570798/2292566), but I lack sufficient reputation.
To add a custom port to the Load Balancer **after** the service fabric cluster has been created you can (in the newer Azure portal):

- Navigate to the load balancer resource for your service fabric cluster.
- Under "Settings" find the "Load balancing rules" option.

  - This will have at least two rules, more if you did setup custom rules during the setup of the cluster.
- Add a new rule.

  - Give it a name
  - 'Port' is the external port you'd like to hit.
  - 'BackendPort' is the port your service is configured to listen on.
  - The defaults on the other settings work in a pinch.

Note if you have multiple ports to enable, they each need their own rule.

I do know the above worked in my 'hello world' sandbox project.

I'm climbing the service fabric learning curve myself so I can't comment with authority on the other settings.

Comment: Thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

Not really related to Service Fabric, it's just how you set up your HTTP response headers in Web API. Recommend tagging this with [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) or [asp.net-web-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api) for a more thorough answer.

Comment: If it is working locally (ie http:\\localhost:30003\api\values) then using the azure fqn and correct port should also work, I would expect. Might have the wrong port, Azure lists a few for the service fabric but tried them all didn't help. There must be a way to call webapi hosted in a node or there would be no point to it.

Comment: The fact that you got prompted to download a file called values leads me to believe that you were actually hitting the endpoint successfully, but that your browser was not interpreting the response's content type header correctly, as Vas suggests. To confirm: were you using the same browser to test locally and in Azure? IE has historically interpreted application/json as downloadable content rather than rendering inline.

Comment: Yes, chrome for both. Good point about the file downloading. I have since tried a webapi app in a stateless service as well as trying a normal azure webapi. The first gave internal 500 error as did the later. Can't access the logs yet to troubleshoot. Next step is to deploy one of the sample apps and see if that works.

Comment: I took one of the demo projects VoiceMailBox, ran it locally and on localhost:8081/voicemailbox/ it ran as expected. Deployed to my Service Fabric site on Azure and I can see it running (all green) on the Service Fabric Explorer. Tried sitename.westus.cloudapp.azure.com:19080/voicemailbox/ as well as sitename.westus.cloudapp.azure.com:8081/voicemailbox/ and just sitename.westus.cloudapp.azure.com/voicemailbox/. None worked. The 19080 one did load a blank page, the rest page not found. I'm stumped. Has anyone even tried this? Can't find a single example.

Answer (score 0):

Tutorials and technical resources around `Azure Service Fabric Stateless Web API` tend to be slightly disjointed, given that the platform and resources are still quite immature.

[This Stateless Web API tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-webapi/), at the time of writing, is very effective.

As prerequisite to the tutorial:

1. Update `Visual Studio` to the latest version (Extensions and Updates)
2. Update the `Service Fabric SDK` to the latest version ([Web Platform Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx))
3. Explicitly specify the `EndPoint Port` attribute (defined in `ServiceManifest.xml`) when [setting up your Azure Service Fabric Cluster](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-creation-via-portal/) `Node Type` parameters

Following these steps will successfully allow deployment to both local and remote clusters, and will expose your Web API endpoints for consumption.